# CLion not showing any symbols when working with Unreal Engine 4.25

Tags: clion, unreal-engine4

So, this is my first time ever using CLion and I've already set it up with Unreal Engine 4.25.

The thing is, the editor does not show any color or symbol in the format, only auto completes when writing variable types and, when hovering over them, it does not show the description of it. It also shows those red squiggles under the class name on the functions and it does not show them anywhere else, even if I make any mistake when coding.

[Screenshot on the IDE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLHEQ.png) [Screenshot on the IDE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQf3.png)

I made sure I set CLion as my code editor in Unreal and installed the engine plugin into the IDE, but still no problem solved. I've also generated the CLion project files into the editor

[Unreal plugin installed on CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Vy2.png) [CLion set as my default code editor in Unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeDwF.png) [CLion plugin installed in Unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPrEw.png)

I'm also a bit unfamiliar with any IDE that is not Visual Studio, so the solution for this might as well be very trivial and I'm not aware of it, so I would appreciate any help you could give me in order to solve this problem with CLion.